# How does Prototype extend Objects?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've been reading up on the Prototype source code while learning Javascript. I've been wondering where is the code that is being used to extend Native Objects.

I've been seeing,

```
Object.extend(Function.prototype, (function() {
Object.extend(String.prototype, (function() {
Object.extend(Number.prototype, (function() {
```

all over the place and I can't find where the .extend function is coming from.

I've seen this:

```
  function extend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source)
      destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
  }
```

at line 194-198 and wonder if this is the one. I can't find out how it is, if it is.

anyway, my question as I stated above is how/where does Prototype extend the Native objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the function you're seeing, later in the code you'll see it used to get `Object.extend`, like this:

```
extend(Object, {
    extend: extend, //here's where the magic gets added
    inspect: inspect,
    toJSON: NATIVE_JSON_STRINGIFY_SUPPORT ? stringify : toJSON,
    toQueryString: toQueryString,
    toHTML: toHTML,
    keys: Object.keys || keys,
    values: values,
    clone: clone,
    isElement: isElement,
    isArray: isArray,
    isHash: isHash,
    isFunction: isFunction,
    isString: isString,
    isNumber: isNumber,
    isDate: isDate,
    isUndefined: isUndefined
});
```

So it's calling `extend()` with itself as a property to add to the`Object` prototype, adding itself as the `.extend` method on `Object`.

Comment: I think I get what you mean here: keys:Object.keys. So Object.keys are actually the Object properties. What does the other '|| keys' do here?

Comment: @Thorpe - It's saying if it *already* has `Object.keys` (a native browser version), use that, if not then use the `keys` function defined in that file: https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/object.js#L308-317

Comment: I thought so :) I believe that your answer was the best at explaining things. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code here:
https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/object.js
 you will see this:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... where do I find this line?

Comment: @Thorpe - https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/object.js#L567-584